# complex operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, complex-numbers

What is wrong with this complex overloading function?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
class complex
{
private:
    float real,imag;
public:
    complex()
    {}
    complex(float r,float i)
    {
        real=r;
        imag=i;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"the complex is \t"<<real<<"+i."<<imag;
    }
    complex operator * (complex c1,complex c2)
    {
        complex t;
        t.real=c1.real*real-imag*c1.imag;
        t.imag=real*c1.imag+c1.real*imag;
        return(t);
    }
};
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    complex c1(4,-5);
    complex c2(9,-2);
    complex c3;
    c3=c1*c2;
    c3.display();
    getch();
}
```

Comment: There's a way to post code so it's properly formatted.  And a live preview on this site, so you know what your post will look like.  Please remember to format your question when you post it.

Comment: If you're having a problem with this code, please tell us what.  Is it failing to compile?  Is it crashing?  Is it giving you a wrong result?  Posting a block of code and saying "fix it" makes you sound like a bad student.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

1. your `operator*` should be defined outside the class (it's a good practice, to support things like casting properly). instead of using `real` and `imag`, use `c2.real` and `c2.imag`.
2. either make this function return by-reference, or implement `operator=` (this one can be inside the class, and should only receive 1 argument - rhs).